# How can I tell Mathematica that $0^0$ is equal to 1

Tags: list-manipulation

I input:  Table[Binomial[3, k] (3 - k)^(3 - k) (k + 1)^(k - 1), {k, 0, 3}].

Mathematica returns: {27, 12, 9, Indeterminate}.

I want Mathematica to return:  {27, 12, 9, 16}.

Comment: Maybe use Limit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Indeterminate expression 0^0 encountered](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60575/indeterminate-expression-00-encountered) Also: [Could I define 0^0 to be 1?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64179/could-i-define-00-to-be-1) and [How can I make Mathematica agree that 0^0 = 1?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/151687/how-can-i-make-mathematica-agree-that-00-1).